# How to make child Form transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, monthcalendar

Am creating a windows application (win form). I want to create a UI something like the attached image.

Am using a form (**called CalendarForm**),that will contains the right side controls (blue background portion)

The issue now am facing is, when am using MDI and setting **CalendarForm** as a child. Then I am not able to sent the opacity to show the MDI parent form background.

Am using below mentioned code in **MDIForm_Load**  method

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
CalendarForm calForm = new CalendarForm();
calForm.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(33, 66, 131);
calForm.Opacity = 0.5d;
calForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
calForm.MdiParent = this;           
calForm.Show();
```

Is there any way to achieve my requirement ?
[image]

Comment: and am facing difficulty to make monthCalendar something similar to this'

Comment: Have you tried using the Color.FromArgb with alpha parameter? No idea if it makes a difference, probably not, but trying is easy enough:
[...] = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue)

Comment: getting this error - "Control does not support transparent background"

Comment: I don't think you want MDI at all - why not just let the form be a child of the main form?

Comment: @Luaan how can i able to show form in another form?

Comment: Just set `Parent`. When either of the windows has focus, both will be visible (with the child obscuring the parent, of course).

Comment: i did like that, then also opacity is not working on child form

Comment: the ultimate requirement is i need to show a child form as transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [Custom Month Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar) created by  [**Patrik Bohman**](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Patrik-Bohman) ,we can make the calendar background transparent.

Answer (score -3):

To make a WinForm transparent you could use the opacity property

```
calForm.Opacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: i need to set the opacity to child form not to the MDI paraent

Comment: @thejustv I have edited my code so it would work for the child Form

Comment: before commenting anything just got through the question carefully, am already using the that line in my code.